# git - remove the files in a remote branch and sync with another branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

There are a few branches branches (master, test1, test2,)

I have just cloned the whole repository and would like to 'sync' test1 and test2 branches. Remotely, test1 has the desired content, test2 is out of date. I would like to:

1. remove the files in the test2 branch (both locally and remotely)
2. sync/merge test2 with test1 so that test2 has the same contents as test1 deleting the current content of test2.

So in other words how would I pull the contents of test1 and put it in test2 (destroying all the current content of test2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably do:

```
git branch -d test2   # Delete test2 locally
git checkout test1
git checkout -b test2 # Recreate test2 locally from test1
git push -f           # Forcibly bring remote test2 into step
```

But do remember the usual caveat; if other people have the upstream `test2`, then overwriting its history is not very friendly.

Comment: Thanks. What would they then they have to do to update test2 on their computers?

Comment: `git pull -f` for the `test2` branch should do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't keep doing it though. What's the correct work flow. I develop some changes. A person working in test1 branch implements them and adds a few more changes. So after a few days. I want my (test2) branch be exactly like his. I can't keep deleting it. Thank you

Comment: Merging. It's not quite clear what your setup is, and the comment box is too small, but basically you'd expect `test1` to merge your changes (either from `test2` or from `master` if you've merged into there), and you merge `test1`'s changes in the other direction. If you need more details, I suggest you ask a question specifically on the workflow.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will ask another question then.